# Php How to Edit and Delete Records from text file clicking on the corresponding button of Records shown

Tags: php

I have two files one is **list.php** and another is **record.php**. Through first file i can add new records and saved it to text file. What I want is when i click on a button corresponding to a particular record row that record should be deleted or edit according to the option choosen, from text file. **list.php** is used to display records. here is my code.
**list.php**

```
$choice = array();
$dataCounter = file("data.txt");
$id = 1;
foreach ($dataCounter as $line)
{
    $line = explode('|', $line);
    $id++;
}

if ($choice == "addRecord")
{
    $fileName = "data.txt";
    $data = fopen($fileName, "a");
    fwrite($data, "$id\t $name\t  $phone\t  $email\t  $address\n");
    fclose($data);
}

//function to display records
function viewRecords()
{
?>
    <table border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="2" width="300">
    <?php
    $theData = file("data.txt");
    foreach ($theData as $key => $lines)
    {

 echo("<tr>");
            list($id, $name, $phone, $email, $address) = split("\t",$lines);
    echo("<td>");
    echo $name;
    echo $phone;
    echo $email;
    echo $address;  
    echo("</td>"); ?> 



    <td>
             <form action="record.php" method="post" name="viewForm" id="viewForm">
              <input type="hidden" name="userid" value= "<?php echo $id; ?>"/>
              <input type="hidden" name="username" value= "<?php echo $name; ?>"/>
              <input type="hidden" name="userphone" value= "<?php echo $phone; ?>"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="useremail" value= "<?php echo $email; ?>"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="useraddress" value= "<?php echo $address; ?>"/>
           <input type="hidden1" name="editId" value= "<?php echo $key; ?>" />
            <input type="submit" id="action" name="action" value="Edit"/>
                </form>

    <input type="submit" id="delete" name="action" value="Delete" onclick="return confirm('Do you want to delete?');"/>
                </td>

        <?php echo("</tr>");
        }
            ?>


    </table>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
    <html>
        <head>
               <title> View Page </title>
        </head>
        <body>



    <div class="header">
                <div style="border:1px solid black; padding:15px; width:800px">
                    <table border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="2" width="300">
                        <tr>
                            <td>ID</td>
                            <td>Name</td>
                            <td>Phone</td>
                            <td>Email</td>


    <td>Address</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>



    </div>
                    <div class="fileSize">
                    <div style="border:1px solid black; padding:15px; width:800px">
                    <?php
                if (filesize('data.txt') == 0)
                {
                    echo "NO DATA FOUND";
                }
            ?>


    </div>

        <div class="viewOptions">
        <div style="border:1px solid black; padding:15px; width:800px">
        <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Add New"/>
    <p>[ <a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>?choice=view">View</a> ]</p>
                    <?php
                    //Main logic what to do when
                    if ($choice == "view")


            { 
                        viewRecords();
                    }
                    ?>
                </div>

        </body>
    </html>




**record.php**

<?php
$name = "";
$phone = "";
$email = "";
$address = "";

if (!empty($_POST["username"])) $name = $_POST["username"];
if (!empty($_POST["userphone"])) $phone = $_POST["userphone"];
if (!empty($_POST["useremail"])) $email= $_POST["useremail"];
if (!empty($_POST["useraddress"])) $address = $_POST["useraddress"];
?>
<html>
    <head>
           <title>User Record Entry</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <center>
            <form action="list.php" method="post" name="recordForm" id="recordForm">
                <table style="border:3px solid black;" width="350">
                    <tr>
                        <td>Name:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="username" id="username" size="21" style="font-family:Verdana; font-size:16px;" value ="<?php echo $name; ?>"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Phone:</td>  
                        <td><input type="text" name="userphone" id="userphone" size="21" style="font-family:Verdana; font-size:16px;" value ="<?php echo $phone; ?>"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Email:</td>  
                        <td><input type="text" name="useremail" id="useremail" size="21" style="font-family:Verdana; font-size:16px;" value ="<?php echo $email; ?>"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Address:</td>  
                        <td><textarea rows="4"columns="28" name="useraddress" id="useraddress"style="font-family:Verdana; font-size:16px;"><?php echo $address;?></textarea></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>                         
                        <td>
                            <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Add"/>
                            <input type="hidden" name="choice" id="choice" value="addRecord"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
        </center>
    </body>
</html>



    enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$name = "";
$phone = "";
$action = "";
$editId = "";

if (!empty($_POST["username"])) $name = $_POST["username"];
if (!empty($_POST["userphone"])) $phone = $_POST["userphone"];
if (!empty($_POST["action"])) $action = $_POST["action"];
?>

<html>
    <body>
        <?php


        if ($action == "add")
        {
            $fileName = "filename.txt";
            $data = fopen($fileName, "a");
            fwrite($data, $name."|---|".$phone."\r\n");
            fclose($data);
        }
        else if($action == "delete")
        {
            $deleteId = $_POST['deleteId'];         
            $readData = file("filename.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);            
            $arrOut = array();

            foreach ($readData as $key => $val)
            {
                 if ($key != $deleteId) $arrOut[] = $val;
            }           

            $strArr = implode("\n",$arrOut);
            $fp = fopen('filename.txt', 'w');
            if (count($readData) < 0)
            {
             fwrite($fp, $strArr."\r\n");
            }
            else
            fwrite($fp, $strArr);   
            fclose($fp);
        }
        else if($action == "edit")
        {   
            $editId= $_POST["editId"];
            $readData = file("filename.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
            $readData[$editId] = ($name."|---|".$phone."|---|".$email."|---|".$address);
            $writeData = implode("\r\n", $readData);
            $fileWrite = fopen('filename.txt', 'w');
            fwrite($fileWrite, $writeData."\r\n"); 
            fclose($fileWrite);
        }


        $fileName = "filename.txt";
        $readData = file("filename.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
        ?>
        <table border="1" width="50%">
            <tr>
                <td>Sr. No</td>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td>Phone No</td>
                <td colspan = "2">Action</td>
            </tr>

        <?php
        $cnt = 1;
        if (count($readData) > 0)
        {
            foreach ($readData as $key => $val)
            {
                list($name, $phone) = array_pad(explode("|---|", $val, 3), 3, null);    
            ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?=$cnt?></td>
                    <td><?=$name?></td>
                    <td><?=$phone?></td>
                    <td>
                        <form action="add.php" method="post" name="editForm" id="editForm">
                            <input type="submit" id="btnEdit" name="btnEdit" value="Edit"/>
                            <input type="hidden" id="editId" name="editId" value="<?php echo $key; ?>"/> 
                            <input type="hidden" name="action" id="action" value="edit"/>
                        </form>
                        <form action="" method="post" name="deleteForm" id="deleteForm">
                            <input type="submit" id="delete" name="delete" value="Delete" onclick="return confirm('Do you want to delete this record?');"/>
                            <input type="hidden" id="deleteId" name="deleteId" value="<?php echo $key; ?>"/>
                            <input type="hidden" name="action" id="action" value="delete"/>
                        </form>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <?php
                $cnt++;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            echo "No Record Found";
        }
        ?>
            <tr>
                <td colspan = "7"><p>[ <a href="add.php">Add New Record</a> ]</p></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

> Blockquote 
>   save one form as**display.php** and other one as **add.php** and copy paste the whole code

```
   <?php
    $action = "";
    if (!empty($_POST["action"])) $action = $_POST["action"];
    $editId = "";
    if ($action == "edit")
    {


    $editId = $_POST["editId"];
            $fileName = "filename.txt";
            $readData = file("filename.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);    


    list($name, $phone) = array_pad(explode("|---|", $readData[$editId], 3), 3, null);  
            $action = "edit";
        $submit = "Update";
        $formTitle = "Edit Record";
    }

    else
    {   
        $name = "";
        $phone = "";
        $email = "";
        $address = "";
        $action = "add";
        $submit = "Add";
        $formTitle = "Add New Record";

}
?>

<html>
    <head>
           <title>Records</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <center>
            <form action="display.php" method="post" name="recordForm" id="recordForm">
            <label><?=$formTitle?></label>
                <table style="border:3px solid black;" width="350">                                     
                    <tr>
                        <td>Name:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="username" id="username" size="21" style="font-family:Verdana; 
                          font-size:16px;" value="<?=$name?>"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Phone:</td>  
                        <td><input type="text" name="userphone" id="userphone" size="21" style="font-family:Verdana; 
                          font-size:16px;" value="<?=$phone?>"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>                         
                        <td>
                            <input type="hidden" id="editId" name="editId" value="<?=$editId?>"/>
                            <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" name="btnSubmit" value="<?=$submit?>"/>
                            <input type="hidden" name="action" id="action" value="<?=$action?>"/> 
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form> 
        </center>
    </body>
</html>
```